# SD driver - Write speed

Tags: embedded

We've been trying to figure out why we only achieve writing speed of ~53MBps on UHS104 cards that claim 90MBps.
Due to hardware constraints, clock frequency supplied to the card is only 148.5 MHz (instead of 208MHz).
Does that mean that we should achieve speed of (148.5 * 4)/8 = 74.25MBps?
Or is our caclulation wrong since it assumes that if card guarantees speed of 90MBps on frequency of 208MHz, then it should guarantee speed of 74.25MBps on frequency of 148.5?

Comment: How do you test the 53Mbyte per second? Do you simply write continously data, or do you use a filesystem driver here? Do you look at the lines with an oscilloscope? Are the blank gaps?

Comment: @jeb Write continously (filesystem overhead wasn't measured). We havn't used oscilloscope yet beacause of physical constraints, but from looking at the program counter I could see that the card spent alot of time at busy state.

Comment: Sometimes I think that these are the only reason that the term "up to" was invented.

Comment: @ssg SanDisk's website states that this is the minimal speed.

Comment: I remember some article *years* ago about system latency, the interesting point being that, with a certain speed mis-match between chips/systems, you could fine one device would run at a speed that *just* misses the "window" for data transfer, so you have to wait 1 extra cycle every time, so the time penalty for going 10% too slow was actually 110%.

Comment: @Shmoopy: their bad :) by the way make sure you turn off buffering and enable write-through to disallow cache-clogging impact your tests.

Comment: What operating system, and which filing system is on the card?

Comment: @Marko threadx /FAT. What I really want to know is what should speed should we expect given that fact that we supply clock of 148.5MHz. I couldn't find anything relevant in the standard.

Comment: @Shmoopy OK. The reason I asked is that non-FAT filing systems tend to perform dreadfully on cards which have erase-block management optimized for FAT32.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's the result with other cards?

Answer (score 1):

The [simplified physical layer spec](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/pls/) states that for maximum performance you need to write full `AU` blocks - usually 2 or 4 MByte, otherwise the card will have to copy data around internally when writing across block boundaries. Unfortunately, most of the `Speed Class Specification` is missing in the 4.13 chapter.

The first AUs may have a different wear level strategy, as they are normally used for the FATs. This could make them slower to write to.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just wondering - what does AU stand for?